# Making .php not required with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm trying to make my links a little easier to write, without the .php.

My rewrite rule is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ([a-z]+)$ $1.php
```

This is the first .htaccess I wrote myself, but it doesn't seem to work.
I'm good with RegExp. And I don't see the issue here.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: The .htaccess tester (http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) tells me that your rule works OK. What issues are you having with it?

Comment: I get an: "Internal Server Error"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure mod_rewrite is enabled in apache config as well as AllowOverride All

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
<Directory "c:/wamp/www/">

    AllowOverride all
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from all

</Directory>
```

To get it workign in wamp
Click on wamp icon in systray
Go to apache
then click on httpd.conf

Search the file for mod_rewrite.so. If that line is commented (#) uncomment it.
It should look like

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Then look for something like

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/www/">
```

You should find a `AllowOverride none` Change it to `AllowOverride all`
Restart your wamp server

Then set your .htaccess to nickb suggestion

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

If it still doesn't work just do a search in the httpd.conf for `AllowOverride none` and change them all to `AllowOverride all`, as there may be a couple

Comment: So i just add this to the .htaccess?

Comment: I updated my post with instructions. You want to make the edit in http.conf

Comment: Thanks, finally I can use the rewriteEngine

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Start from here: http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/sitemanagement/urlrewriting.html

Answer (score 1):

Even though yours works for alphabetic filenames, this is what I've used regardless of the name / path of the file to omit the `.php` extension:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

It makes sure you're not trying to request a directory, and that the file that was requested is a PHP file.